# Cracking the Enigma?

Tags: code-golf, string

#### Introduction

The Enigma was one of the first electro-mechanical rotor cipher machines used in World War II. That means that after a single letter is coded, it would change the key for the next letter. This was considered *unbreakable* by the Germans, due to the enormous key space. Even brute-forcing was almost impossible. However, there was a design error in the Enigma. Encrypting a letter would never result into itself. That means that the letter `A` can encrypt to every letter except the letter `A`.

Let's take an example of a coded message:

```
BHGEFXWFTIUPITHHLPETTTCLOEWOELMRXXPAKAXMAMTXXUDLTWTNHKELEPPLHPRQ
```

A typical German word was `WETTERBERICHT`, or weather report in English. With the principe above, we can determine at which locations the word could possibly be:

```
BHGEFXWFTIUPITHHLPETTTCLOEWOELMRXXPAKAXMAMTXXUDLTWTNHKELEPPLHPRQ
WETTERBERICHT
         ^
```

This is not possible, because the `I` can't be encrypted to itself, so we move on 1 place:

```
BHGEFXWFTIUPITHHLPETTTCLOEWOELMRXXPAKAXMAMTXXUDLTWTNHKELEPPLHPRQ
 WETTERBERICHT
             ^
```

This is also not possible, so we move another place again:

```
BHGEFXWFTIUPITHHLPETTTCLOEWOELMRXXPAKAXMAMTXXUDLTWTNHKELEPPLHPRQ
  WETTERBERICHT
   ^
```

This again is not possible. In fact, the first possible occurence of `WETTERBERICHT` is:

```
BHGEFXWFTIUPITHHLPETTTCLOEWOELMRXXPAKAXMAMTXXUDLTWTNHKELEPPLHPRQ
             WETTERBERICHT
0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123
             ^
             13
```

So, we return the 0-indexed position of the first possible occurence, which is **13**.

#### The Task

- Given a coded message and a word, find the index of the **first possible occurence**.
- Assume that only basic uppercase alphabetic characters will be used (`ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`).
- If no occurence is found, you can output any **negative** integer, character, or nothing (e.g. `-1`, `X`).
- Input may be accepted as argument, on seperate newlines, lists or anything else.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the submission with the least amount of bytes wins!

#### Test cases

```
Input: BHGEFXWFTIUPITHHLPETTTCLOEWOELM, WETTERBERICHT
Output: 13

Input: ABCDEFGHIJKL, HELLO
Output: 0

Input: EEEEEEEEEEEE, HELLO
Output: -1

Input: XEEFSLBSELDJMADNADKDPSSPRNEBWIENPF, DEUTSCHLAND
Output: 11

Input: HKKH, JJJJJ
Output: -1
```

Comment: Umm, why does the encoded string change in the middle of the example?

Comment: @Doorknob冰  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: There are issues with the introduction:
1. it wasn't considered unbreakable because of the key space, but because of the system that a letter changes what it is translated to
2. "Encrypting a letter would never result into itself." - yes it would, after the number of available characters it would have to repeat one.

Comment: @Zelphir with encrypting to itself, I meant that the `E` would never result into an `E`. That is what this whole challenge is about.

Comment: Can we use 1-indexing if that's our language's default?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Pyth, 14 bytes

```
f!s.eqb@>zTkQ0
```

I'm not sure if this is Ok but if the input is impossible, nothing is written to stdout and a zero division error is written to stderr. Takes the input on 2 lines, the second one is surrounded by quotes.

Explanation:

```
               - autoassign z to first input
               - autoassign Q to second input
f            0 - The first value starting from 0 where the output is truthy
   .e       Q  - Enumerate over the second value
        >zT    - z[T:]
       @   k   - The kth item (number in enumeration)
      b        - The character in the enumeration
     q         - Are the two characters equal?
  s            - Sum the values
 !             - Invert them (want first where there isn't a collision)
```

[Try it here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=f!s.eqb%40%3EzTkQ0&input=BHGEFXWFTIUPITHHLPETTTCLOEWOELM%0A%22WETTERBERICHT%22&debug=0)

Answer (score 57):

## JavaScript, 40

```
(c,p)=>c.search(p.replace(/./g,"[^$&]"))
```

Using `replace`, this maps the plaintext input into a regular expression of form `/[^H][^E][^L][^L][^O]/` (e.g., for plaintext input `HELLO`) and then uses `search` to test for the first index of the ciphertext substring that matches that regex. This regex means "a pattern where the first character is not `H`, the second character is not `E`, etc."

[`$&` is a special sequence for `replace` output](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) that substitutes in the value matched by the first `replace` argument (in this case, each single character matched by `/./`).

Comment: Oh, wow, that's a really clever solution!

Comment: I didn't know about `$&`! Thanks for teaching my something today.

Comment: @ETHproductions Me neither, until today! I also learned about [$` and `$'`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) in the process of researching this answer, which provide "the portion of the string that precedes/follows the matched substring"

Comment: Wow, that's awesome! I should read the docs more often ;)

Answer (score 46):

### [Turing Machine Simulator](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html) - 15660 bytes (Non-Competing)

Can't have an Enigma challenge without turing machine code.

```
0 * * l 0
0 _ _ l ,
, _ , l 1
1 _ 0 r 2
2 * * r 2
2 , * r 3
3 * * r 3
3 , * r 4
4 * * r 4
4 _ * r 13
4 A a l a'                                                                                                                                                                                                        
4 B b l b'                                                                                                                                                                                                        
4 C c l c'                                                                                                                                                                                                        
4 D d l d'                                                                                                                                                                                                        
4 E e l e'                                                                                                                                                                                                        
4 F f l f'                                                                                                                                                                                                        
4 G g l g'                                                                                                                                                                                                        
4 H h l h'                                                                                                                                                                                                        
4 I i l i'                                                                                                                                                                                                        
4 J j l j'                                                                                                                                                                                                        
4 K k l k'                                                                                                                                                                                                        
4 L l l l'                                                                                                                                                                                                        
4 M m l m'                                                                                                                                                                                                        
4 N n l n'                                                                                                                                                                                                        
4 O o l o'                                                                                                                                                                                                        
4 P p l p'                                                                                                                                                                                                        
4 Q q l q'                                                                                                                                                                                                        
4 R r l r'                                                                                                                                                                                                        
4 S s l s'                                                                                                                                                                                                        
4 T t l t'                                                                                                                                                                                                        
4 U u l u'                                                                                                                                                                                                        
4 V v l v'                                                                                                                                                                                                        
4 W w l w'                                                                                                                                                                                                        
4 X x l x'                                                                                                                                                                                                        
4 Y y l y'                                                                                                                                                                                                        
4 Z z l z'
a' * * l a'
a' , * l a
b' * * l b'
b' , * l b
c' * * l c'
c' , * l c
d' * * l d'
d' , * l d
e' * * l e'
e' , * l e
f' * * l f'
f' , * l f
g' * * l g'
g' , * l g
h' * * l h'
h' , * l h
i' * * l i'
i' , * l i
j' * * l j'
j' , * l j
k' * * l k'
k' , * l k
l' * * l l'
l' , * l l
m' * * l m'
m' , * l m
n' * * l n'
n' , * l n
o' * * l o'
o' , * l o
p' * * l p'
p' , * l p
q' * * l q'
q' , * l q
r' * * l r'
r' , * l r
s' * * l s'
s' , * l s
t' * * l t'
t' , * l t
u' * * l u'
u' , * l u
v' * * l v'
v' , * l v
w' * * l w'
w' , * l w
x' * * l x'
x' , * l x
y' * * l y'
y' , * l y
z' * * l z'
z' , * l z

a * * l a
a _ * r A
a a * r A
a b * r A
a c * r A
a d * r A
a e * r A
a f * r A
a g * r A
a h * r A
a i * r A
a j * r A
a k * r A
a l * r A
a m * r A
a n * r A
a o * r A
a p * r A
a q * r A
a r * r A
a s * r A
a t * r A
a u * r A
a v * r A
a w * r A
a x * r A
a y * r A
a z * r A
b * * l b
b _ * r B
b a * r B
b b * r B
b c * r B
b d * r B
b e * r B
b f * r B
b g * r B
b h * r B
b i * r B
b j * r B
b k * r B
b l * r B
b m * r B
b n * r B
b o * r B
b p * r B
b q * r B
b r * r B
b s * r B
b t * r B
b u * r B
b v * r B
b w * r B
b x * r B
b y * r B
b z * r B
c * * l c
c _ * r C
c a * r C
c b * r C
c c * r C
c d * r C
c e * r C
c f * r C
c g * r C
c h * r C
c i * r C
c j * r C
c k * r C
c l * r C
c m * r C
c n * r C
c o * r C
c p * r C
c q * r C
c r * r C
c s * r C
c t * r C
c u * r C
c v * r C
c w * r C
c x * r C
c y * r C
c z * r C
d * * l d
d _ * r D
d a * r D
d b * r D
d c * r D
d d * r D
d e * r D
d f * r D
d g * r D
d h * r D
d i * r D
d j * r D
d k * r D
d l * r D
d m * r D
d n * r D
d o * r D
d p * r D
d q * r D
d r * r D
d s * r D
d t * r D
d u * r D
d v * r D
d w * r D
d x * r D
d y * r D
d z * r D
e * * l e
e _ * r E
e a * r E
e b * r E
e c * r E
e d * r E
e e * r E
e f * r E
e g * r E
e h * r E
e i * r E
e j * r E
e k * r E
e l * r E
e m * r E
e n * r E
e o * r E
e p * r E
e q * r E
e r * r E
e s * r E
e t * r E
e u * r E
e v * r E
e w * r E
e x * r E
e y * r E
e z * r E
f * * l f
f _ * r F
f a * r F
f b * r F
f c * r F
f d * r F
f e * r F
f f * r F
f g * r F
f h * r F
f i * r F
f j * r F
f k * r F
f l * r F
f m * r F
f n * r F
f o * r F
f p * r F
f q * r F
f r * r F
f s * r F
f t * r F
f u * r F
f v * r F
f w * r F
f x * r F
f y * r F
f z * r F
g * * l g
g _ * r G
g a * r G
g b * r G
g c * r G
g d * r G
g e * r G
g f * r G
g g * r G
g h * r G
g i * r G
g j * r G
g k * r G
g l * r G
g m * r G
g n * r G
g o * r G
g p * r G
g q * r G
g r * r G
g s * r G
g t * r G
g u * r G
g v * r G
g w * r G
g x * r G
g y * r G
g z * r G
h * * l h
h _ * r H
h a * r H
h b * r H
h c * r H
h d * r H
h e * r H
h f * r H
h g * r H
h h * r H
h i * r H
h j * r H
h k * r H
h l * r H
h m * r H
h n * r H
h o * r H
h p * r H
h q * r H
h r * r H
h s * r H
h t * r H
h u * r H
h v * r H
h w * r H
h x * r H
h y * r H
h z * r H
i * * l i
i _ * r I
i a * r I
i b * r I
i c * r I
i d * r I
i e * r I
i f * r I
i g * r I
i h * r I
i i * r I
i j * r I
i k * r I
i l * r I
i m * r I
i n * r I
i o * r I
i p * r I
i q * r I
i r * r I
i s * r I
i t * r I
i u * r I
i v * r I
i w * r I
i x * r I
i y * r I
i z * r I
j * * l j
j _ * r J
j a * r J
j b * r J
j c * r J
j d * r J
j e * r J
j f * r J
j g * r J
j h * r J
j i * r J
j j * r J
j k * r J
j l * r J
j m * r J
j n * r J
j o * r J
j p * r J
j q * r J
j r * r J
j s * r J
j t * r J
j u * r J
j v * r J
j w * r J
j x * r J
j y * r J
j z * r J
k * * l k
k _ * r K
k a * r K
k b * r K
k c * r K
k d * r K
k e * r K
k f * r K
k g * r K
k h * r K
k i * r K
k j * r K
k k * r K
k l * r K
k m * r K
k n * r K
k o * r K
k p * r K
k q * r K
k r * r K
k s * r K
k t * r K
k u * r K
k v * r K
k w * r K
k x * r K
k y * r K
k z * r K
l * * l l
l _ * r L
l a * r L
l b * r L
l c * r L
l d * r L
l e * r L
l f * r L
l g * r L
l h * r L
l i * r L
l j * r L
l k * r L
l l * r L
l m * r L
l n * r L
l o * r L
l p * r L
l q * r L
l r * r L
l s * r L
l t * r L
l u * r L
l v * r L
l w * r L
l x * r L
l y * r L
l z * r L
m * * l m
m _ * r M
m a * r M
m b * r M
m c * r M
m d * r M
m e * r M
m f * r M
m g * r M
m h * r M
m i * r M
m j * r M
m k * r M
m l * r M
m m * r M
m n * r M
m o * r M
m p * r M
m q * r M
m r * r M
m s * r M
m t * r M
m u * r M
m v * r M
m w * r M
m x * r M
m y * r M
m z * r M
n * * l n
n _ * r N
n a * r N
n b * r N
n c * r N
n d * r N
n e * r N
n f * r N
n g * r N
n h * r N
n i * r N
n j * r N
n k * r N
n l * r N
n m * r N
n n * r N
n o * r N
n p * r N
n q * r N
n r * r N
n s * r N
n t * r N
n u * r N
n v * r N
n w * r N
n x * r N
n y * r N
n z * r N
o * * l o
o _ * r O
o a * r O
o b * r O
o c * r O
o d * r O
o e * r O
o f * r O
o g * r O
o h * r O
o i * r O
o j * r O
o k * r O
o l * r O
o m * r O
o n * r O
o o * r O
o p * r O
o q * r O
o r * r O
o s * r O
o t * r O
o u * r O
o v * r O
o w * r O
o x * r O
o y * r O
o z * r O
p * * l p
p _ * r P
p a * r P
p b * r P
p c * r P
p d * r P
p e * r P
p f * r P
p g * r P
p h * r P
p i * r P
p j * r P
p k * r P
p l * r P
p m * r P
p n * r P
p o * r P
p p * r P
p q * r P
p r * r P
p s * r P
p t * r P
p u * r P
p v * r P
p w * r P
p x * r P
p y * r P
p z * r P
q * * l q
q _ * r Q
q a * r Q
q b * r Q
q c * r Q
q d * r Q
q e * r Q
q f * r Q
q g * r Q
q h * r Q
q i * r Q
q j * r Q
q k * r Q
q l * r Q
q m * r Q
q n * r Q
q o * r Q
q p * r Q
q q * r Q
q r * r Q
q s * r Q
q t * r Q
q u * r Q
q v * r Q
q w * r Q
q x * r Q
q y * r Q
q z * r Q
r * * l r
r _ * r R
r a * r R
r b * r R
r c * r R
r d * r R
r e * r R
r f * r R
r g * r R
r h * r R
r i * r R
r j * r R
r k * r R
r l * r R
r m * r R
r n * r R
r o * r R
r p * r R
r q * r R
r r * r R
r s * r R
r t * r R
r u * r R
r v * r R
r w * r R
r x * r R
r y * r R
r z * r R
s * * l s
s _ * r S
s a * r S
s b * r S
s c * r S
s d * r S
s e * r S
s f * r S
s g * r S
s h * r S
s i * r S
s j * r S
s k * r S
s l * r S
s m * r S
s n * r S
s o * r S
s p * r S
s q * r S
s r * r S
s s * r S
s t * r S
s u * r S
s v * r S
s w * r S
s x * r S
s y * r S
s z * r S
t * * l t
t _ * r T
t a * r T
t b * r T
t c * r T
t d * r T
t e * r T
t f * r T
t g * r T
t h * r T
t i * r T
t j * r T
t k * r T
t l * r T
t m * r T
t n * r T
t o * r T
t p * r T
t q * r T
t r * r T
t s * r T
t t * r T
t u * r T
t v * r T
t w * r T
t x * r T
t y * r T
t z * r T
u * * l u
u _ * r U
u a * r U
u b * r U
u c * r U
u d * r U
u e * r U
u f * r U
u g * r U
u h * r U
u i * r U
u j * r U
u k * r U
u l * r U
u m * r U
u n * r U
u o * r U
u p * r U
u q * r U
u r * r U
u s * r U
u t * r U
u u * r U
u v * r U
u w * r U
u x * r U
u y * r U
u z * r U
v * * l v
v _ * r V
v a * r V
v b * r V
v c * r V
v d * r V
v e * r V
v f * r V
v g * r V
v h * r V
v i * r V
v j * r V
v k * r V
v l * r V
v m * r V
v n * r V
v o * r V
v p * r V
v q * r V
v r * r V
v s * r V
v t * r V
v u * r V
v v * r V
v w * r V
v x * r V
v y * r V
v z * r V
w * * l w
w _ * r W
w a * r W
w b * r W
w c * r W
w d * r W
w e * r W
w f * r W
w g * r W
w h * r W
w i * r W
w j * r W
w k * r W
w l * r W
w m * r W
w n * r W
w o * r W
w p * r W
w q * r W
w r * r W
w s * r W
w t * r W
w u * r W
w v * r W
w w * r W
w x * r W
w y * r W
w z * r W
x * * l x
x _ * r X
x a * r X
x b * r X
x c * r X
x d * r X
x e * r X
x f * r X
x g * r X
x h * r X
x i * r X
x j * r X
x k * r X
x l * r X
x m * r X
x n * r X
x o * r X
x p * r X
x q * r X
x r * r X
x s * r X
x t * r X
x u * r X
x v * r X
x w * r X
x x * r X
x y * r X
x z * r X
y * * l y
y _ * r Y
y a * r Y
y b * r Y
y c * r Y
y d * r Y
y e * r Y
y f * r Y
y g * r Y
y h * r Y
y i * r Y
y j * r Y
y k * r Y
y l * r Y
y m * r Y
y n * r Y
y o * r Y
y p * r Y
y q * r Y
y r * r Y
y s * r Y
y t * r Y
y u * r Y
y v * r Y
y w * r Y
y x * r Y
y y * r Y
y z * r Y
z * * l z
z , * r Z
z a * r Z
z b * r Z
z c * r Z
z d * r Z
z e * r Z
z f * r Z
z g * r Z
z h * r Z
z i * r Z
z j * r Z
z k * r Z
z l * r Z
z m * r Z
z n * r Z
z o * r Z
z p * r Z
z q * r Z
z r * r Z
z s * r Z
z t * r Z
z u * r Z
z v * r Z
z w * r Z
z x * r Z
z y * r Z
z z * r Z
A * * * 5
A A * l 6
B * * * 5
B B * l 6
C * * * 5
C C * l 6
D * * * 5
D D * l 6
E * * * 5
E E * l 6
F * * * 5
F F * l 6
G * * * 5
G G * l 6
H * * * 5
H H * l 6
I * * * 5
I I * l 6
J * * * 5
J J * l 6
K * * * 5
K K * l 6
L * * * 5
L L * l 6
M * * * 5
M M * l 6
N * * * 5
N N * l 6
O * * * 5
O O * l 6
P * * * 5
P P * l 6
Q * * * 5
Q Q * l 6
R * * * 5
R R * l 6
S * * * 5
S S * l 6
T * * * 5
T T * l 6
U * * * 5
U U * l 6
V * * * 5
V V * l 6
W * * * 5
W W * l 6
X * * * 5
X X * l 6
Y * * * 5
Y Y * l 6
Z * * * 5
Z Z * l 6
5 , * r 15
5 A a r 7
5 B b r 7
5 C c r 7
5 D d r 7
5 E e r 7
5 F f r 7
5 G g r 7
5 H h r 7
5 I i r 7
5 J j r 7
5 K k r 7
5 L l r 7
5 M m r 7
5 N n r 7
5 O o r 7
5 P p r 7
5 Q q r 7
5 R r r 7
5 S s r 7
5 T t r 7
5 U u r 7
5 V v r 7
5 W w r 7
5 X x r 7
5 Y y r 7
5 Z z r 7
7 * * r 7
7 , * r 4
6 * * l 6
6 _ * r 8
8 * _ r 9
9 * * r 9
9 _ * l 10
9 a A r 9
9 b B r 9
9 c C r 9
9 d D r 9
9 e E r 9
9 f F r 9
9 g G r 9
9 h H r 9
9 i I r 9
9 j J r 9
9 k K r 9
9 l L r 9
9 m M r 9
9 n N r 9
9 o O r 9
9 p P r 9
9 q Q r 9
9 r R r 9
9 s S r 9
9 t T r 9
9 u U r 9
9 v V r 9
9 w W r 9
9 x X r 9
9 y Y r 9
9 z Z r 9
10 * * l 10
10 , * l 11
11 * * l 11
11 , * l 12
12 _ 1 r 2
12 0 1 r 2
12 1 2 r 2
12 2 3 r 2
12 3 4 r 2
12 4 5 r 2
12 5 6 r 2
12 6 7 r 2
12 7 8 r 2
12 8 9 r 2
12 9 0 l 12
13 * _ l 13
13 , _ l 14
14 * _ l 14
14 , _ l halt
15 * * r 15
15 _ * l 16
16 * _ l 16
16 , _ l 17
17 * _ l 17
17 , _ l 18
18 * _ l 18
18 _ x * halt
```

[Test it out here](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html?1b6a7eb727ffd1e51882)

Brief overview:

1. Set up a counter on the left
2. Find first uppercase letter in target and make it lowercase. If all letters are lowercase move to step 5.
3. Find first uppercase letter in code. If most recent letter matches, move on to step 4. Else make letter lowercase and go back to step 2.
4. Increment counter, make all letters capital, delete first letter in code. Go back to step 2. If no letters are left in code, return clear tape and print x.
5. Clear all the tape but the counter.

Comment: Also, when testing, the format of the input should be: code,target (no space)

Comment: How long did it take to make this?

Comment: Started my homework at 2:00. Got distracted at 2:15. Started this at 2.20. Posted this at 4:20. So about 2 hours.

Comment: +1, in PPCGSE, it doesn't have to be competing to be appreciated!

Comment: [9575 bytes](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html?ce96896e95f52746842105ead3fdc48e) (and the current bytecount in the header is false, there are extraneous spaces and some unnecessarily long state names).

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer, Your code seems to have a syntax error on line 21.

Comment: @ouflak Try clicking "Reset" and then "Run", there's no syntax error. Looks like a false alarm there.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer, No that code will definitely error. It will run through until it hits that line. Then it will die. Also, lines 57 and 58 will never run (they are commented out with the semicolon).

Answer (score 8):

## SWI-Prolog, 115 bytes

```
a(S,W,R):-length(S,L),length(W,M),N is L-M,between(0,N,I),\+ (between(0,M,J),K is I+J,nth0(J,W,A),nth0(K,S,A)),R=I.
```

Usage example: `` a(`ABCDEFGHIJKL`,`HELLO`,R). ``. This uses the character codes strings declared with backticks. The answer is unified with `R`. If no match is found, this outputs `false.`.

#### Explanation:

```
a(S,W,R):-
    length(S,L),length(W,M),     
    N is L-M,
    between(0,N,I),             % I is successively unified with an integer between 0 
                                % and the last possible index of the coded message

    \+ (                        % This will only be true if what's inside the parentheses 
                                % cannot be proven to be true

        between(0,M,J),         % J is successively unified with an integer between 0 
                                % and the length of the desired word
        K is I+J,
        nth0(J,W,A),nth0(K,S,A) % Check if one letter is the same in both string at 
                                % the same index
    ),                          % If it the case, then it will be 'true' and thus 
                                % the predicate \+ will be false, meaning we need to
                                % backtrack to try a different value of I

    R=I.                        % If we get here it means it didn't find any matching 
                                % letter for this value of I, which is then the answer.
```

[Try it  here](http://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/EpBwLrkw.pl)

Answer (score 7):

## CJam, <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```
ll:A,ew{A.=:+!}#
```

[Try it here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=ll%3AA%2Cew%7BA.%3D%3A%2B!%7D%23&input=BHGEFXWFTIUPITHHLPETTTCLOEWOELM%0AWETTERBERICHT).

Thanks to @PeterTaylor for saving a byte.

Explanation:

```
ll:A,ew    e# Finds every slice in the coded message with the length of the word
{A.=:+     e# Compare the characters in each slice to the characters in the word, and add up the result. If the sum is zero, then the slice and the word have no characters in common.
!}#        e# Invert truthiness (0 -> 1, non-0 -> 0) Return index of first truthy value.
```

Comment: `array block #` can save you a char: `ll:A,ew{A.=:+!}#`

Comment: Amazing how far CJam can be golfed in almost every task... :-o

Comment: @agtoever I wouldn't say it's really golfing, because 17 bytes was my very first try. The key feature is `ew` (make slices), everything else just follows.

Answer (score 7):

### Ruby, <s>91</s> 79 bytes

```ruby
->a,b{[*a.chars.each_cons(b.size)].index{|x|x.zip(b.chars).all?{|y|y.uniq==y}}}
```

Curse you, `Enumerator`! Why do I have to convert from string to array to Enumerator to array and waste precious bytes? >:(

```ruby
->a,b{                  # define lambda
[*                      # convert to array...
  a.chars               # get enumerator from string
  .each_cons(b.size)    # each consecutive group of (b.size) letters
]
.index{|x|              # find index of...
  x.zip(b.chars)        # zip group with second input string
  .all?{|y|             # is the block true for every element?
    y.uniq==y           # uniqueify results in same array (no dups)
}}}
```

Comment: Using `[*...]` as a golfy alternative to #to_a is a nice touch.

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 27 bytes

```
jYbZ)tnb!wlhYCw!=a~ftn?1)1-
```

#### Examples

```
>> matl jYbZ)tnb!wlhYCw!=a~ftn?1)1-
> EEEEEEEEEEEE, HELLO

>> matl jYbZ)tnb!wlhYCw!=a~ftn?1)1-
> XEEFSLBSELDJMADNADKDPSSPRNEBWIENPF, DEUTSCHLAND
11
```

#### Explanation

```
j           % input string
YbZ)        % split into two strings based on space. Trailing comma is not a problem
tnb!wlhYC   % arrange first string into sliding columns of the size of the second
w!=         % compare with transposed second string, element-wise with broadcast
a~          % detect columns where all values are 0 (meaning unequal characters)
f           % find indices of such columns
tn?         % if there's at least one such column
1)1-        % pick index of the first and subtract 1 for 0-based indexing
```

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, 72 bytes

```
l=length
h i w s|l s<l w= -1|and$zipWith(/=)w s=i|1<2=h(i+1)w$tail s
h 0
```

Usage: `h 0 "DEUTSCHLAND"  "XEEFSLBSELDJMADNADKDPSSPRNEBWIENPF"` -> `11`.

Simple recursive approach: if the word `w`can be placed at the beginning of the string `s`, return the index counter `i`, else repeat with `i` incremented and the tail of `s`. Stop and return `-1` if the length of `s` is less than the length of `w`.

Answer (score 4):

### Python 2.7, 111 characters

Tries all starting positions (a) and checks of any of the letters match (using the list comprehension). It returns "None" (Python's "NULL") if nothing is found (the for loop end and nothing is returned, which defaults to "None".

```
def d(c,s):
 for a in range(len(c)):
  if a not in [((c+s)[a+i:]).index(l)+a for i,l in enumerate(s)]:
   return a
```

Testsuite:

```
cases = {
         ("BHGEFXWFTIUPITHHLPETTTCLOEWOELM","WETTERBERICHT"):13,
         ("ABCDEFGHIJKL","HELLO"):0,
         ("EEEEEEEEEEEE","HELLO"):-1,
         ("XEEFSLBSELDJMADNADKDPSSPRNEBWIENPF","DEUTSCHLAND"):11
        }

for idx,(code,string) in enumerate(cases):
    output=d(code,string)
    print "Case: {}: d({:<35},{:<16}) gives: {}. Correct answer is: {}.".format(idx+1,code,string,output,cases[(code,string)])
```

Comment: You actually have 114 bytes, not 111. Here is a 106-byte version: `def d(c,s):
 for a in range(len(c)):
  if a not in[a+(c+s)[a+i:].index(l)for i,l in enumerate(s)]:return a`

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 48 bytes

```
[S:W]hlL,WlM,L-M=:0reI,'(0:MeJ+I=:SrmA,W:JmA),I.
```

This is a direct translation of my Prolog answer. The `brachylog_main/2` generated predicate expects a list of two character codes strings with the coded string first as input, and returns the index as output, e.g. `` brachylog_main([`ABCDEFGHIJKL`,`HELLO`],R). ``.

#### Explanation

```
[S:W]                                            § Unify the input with the list [S,W]

     hlL,WlM,                                    § L and M are the length of S and W

             L-M=:0reI,                          § Enumerate integers between 0 and the 
                                                 § last possible index

                       '(                   ),I. § Unify the output with the current 
                                                 § enumerated integer if what's inside the 
                                                 § parenthesis cannot be proven to be true

                         0:MeJ                   § Enumerate integers between 0 and the
                                                 § length of the word desired

                              +I=:SrmA,W:JmA     § Check if both strings contain at matching
                                                 § indexes the same letter (unified with A)
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, <s>129</s> <s>121</s> <s>118</s> <s>119<sup>*</sup></s> 118 bytes

```
(w,t){for(j=0;(x=t.length)<(y=w.length);t=' '+t,j++){for(a=i=0;++i<y;)w[i]==t[i]?a=1:a;if(!a)break}return x==y?-1:j}
```

`w` is the coded message, `t` is the test string. This doesn't use regexes, but just compares letter by letter, shifting the test string (i.e. "WETTERBERICHT") by appending space before it. Easy and boring.

---

<sup>* test case with no match didn't work, now it does</sup>

Answer (score 3):

## Japt, 12 bytes (non-competitive)

```
UàVr'."[^$&]
```

I'm gonna need some help with this one.

Comment: Uhhh... Japt doesn't have `.search`? *facepalm*

Comment: This can now be done with `UàVr'."[^$&]` for 12.

Comment: Cool, we're winning now!

Comment: Since the latest revision of this answer uses functionality that postdates the question, I'm marking it as non-competitive.

Comment: Oh forgot about that :P Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>14</s> <s>13</s> 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ŒIgùÅΔø€Ëà≠
```

-1 byte thanks to *@ovs*.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6CTP9MM7D7eem3J4x6OmNYe7Dy941Lng/38nD3dXt4hwtxDP0ADPEA8PnwDXkJAQZx9/13B/Vx9frnAg1zXIyTXI09kjBAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##VYsxCsIwFIavIpl7B2maF1/a1zY0KS2UggoiTg6C4OAiKIhb8QA9gAfQObh6iF6kVif9xv/7/vVmNl8t@u1uzEbdqRmx8W6a98@mXLqHO76upbt3h5u7uLY7t/3e66uKcZyALAtpVa6VRSQN1tqAUihSoJh5rBgGyDhkKkDLaq9iPg8EyAmqMKIhQCBKvwJ@@BMlgDTEDZAIY18kvoiENkZnCfBCQaLlkAvIrQmQ/ER8TxhFOMzhB1bXbw).

**Explanation:**

```python
Œ            # Get all substrings of the first (implicit) input
 Ig          # Get the length of the second input
   ù         # Only leave the substrings of that length
    ÅΔ       # Find the first (0-based) index which is truthy for:
             # (which results in -1 if none are truthy)
      ø      #  Zip/transpose; create pairs of the characters in the current substring
             #  and the second (implicit) input
       €Ë    #  Check for each if both characters are equal (1 if truthy; 0 if falsey)
         à   #  Get the maximum (basically equal to an `any` builtin)
          ≠  #  And invert the boolean (!= 1)
             # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: Dude, this was totally supposed to be @Emigna's answer ;). I wanted to come here and make a joke about him answering an adnan-question with almost-his-name in it. +1  (Noticed you answered 4 years after-the-fact after I posted this after-the-fact comment).

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn When I saw the challenge I thought the same thing, but _@Emigna_ usually answers new answers and doesn't look that often at existing answers. So since this one didn't had any 05AB1E answers I figured I'd add one. You're indeed right that _@Emigna_ would have been best suited to answer this challenge. ;p

Comment: [13 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6CTP9MM7z209vONR05rD3YcXPOpcUGuY/f@/k4e7q1tEuFuIZ2iAZ4iHh0@Aa0hIiLOPv2u4v6uPL1c4kOsa5OQa5OnsEQIA) by using `ε` instead of `ʒ` to get rid of `D`.

Comment: @ovs Thanks, that actually opens up 2 more bytes to save with `ÅΔ`! :)

Answer (score 2):

## PHP – 155 bytes

```
<?php for($p=$argv[1],$q=$argv[2],$l=strlen($q),$i=0,$r=-1;$i<strlen($p)-$l;$i++)if(levenshtein($q,substr($p,$i,$l),2,1,2)==$l){$r=$i;break;}echo$r."\n";
```

Save as `crack.php` and run with the arguments in the command line. E.g.:

```
$ php crack.php BHGEFXWFTIUPITHHLPETTTCLOEWOELM WETTERBERICHT
13
```

Comment: You can save *25 bytes* and golf it down to **130 bytes**: `for($r=-1;$i<strlen($p=$argv[1])-$l=strlen($q=$argv[2]);$i++)if(levenshtein($q,substr($p,$i,$l),2,1,2)==$l&&$r=$i)break;echo"$r↵";`

Comment: @insertusernamehere - Wow, that's impressive! So much so that I wouldn't feel right using it! I thought I was being clever using `levenshtein`, but probably a straightforward iteration within an iteration could do it in fewer bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## TeaScript, 14 bytes <s>20</s>

```
xc(yl#`[^${l}]
```

Similar to @aspillers clever JavaScript [solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68194/40695).

### Explanation

```
             // Implicit: x = 1st input, y = 2nd input
x            // First input
 c           // returns index of regex match
 yl#         // Loop through every char in `y`
    `[^${l}] // Replace template, ${l} because current char in `y`
```

Comment: Does `$&` not work in place of `${l}`?

Comment: @ETHproductions not in this case because I'm using a loop rather than a replace

Answer (score 2):

## , 14 chars / 25 bytes

```
îĊⱮ(í,↪`⁅⦃$}]`
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter.html?eval=true&input=%5B%22BHGEFXWFTIUPITHHLPETTTCLOEWOELM%22%2C%22WETTERBERICHT%22%5D&code=%C3%AE%C4%8A%E2%B1%AE%28%C3%AD%2C%E2%86%AA%60%E2%81%85%E2%A6%83%24%7D%5D%60)</kbd>

Kudos to @apsillers for the idea.

## Explanation

```
               // implicit: î = input1, í = input2
îĊ             // search for first occurrence of:
  Ɱ(í,↪`⁅⦃$}]` // regex created by wrapping each word in [^ and ] (negation matches)
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, is there a reason why?

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, <s>43</s> 36 bytes

edit: String interpolation inside string interpolation inside a regex, yikes.

The lazy approach: translates the word to a "negative" regex -- The `=~` operator does the rest.

```rb
->m,w{m=~/#{"[^#{w.chars*'][^'}]"}/}
```

Test:

```rb
f=->m,w{m=~/#{"[^#{w.chars*'][^'}]"}/}

require "minitest/autorun"

describe :f do
  it "works for the given test cases" do
    assert_equal 13, f["BHGEFXWFTIUPITHHLPETTTCLOEWOELM", "WETTERBERICHT"]
    assert_equal 0, f["ABCDEFGHIJKL", "HELLO"]
    assert_equal nil, f["EEEEEEEEEEEE", "HELLO"]
    assert_equal 11, f["XEEFSLBSELDJMADNADKDPSSPRNEBWIENPF", "DEUTSCHLAND"]
    assert_equal nil, f["HKKH", "JJJJJ"]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 79 bytes

```python
lambda x,y:[sum(map(str.__eq__,x[i:],y))for i in range(len(x)-len(y))].index(0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY5Ba4NAEIXP9Vd4212wodCb0IO6Y1bdqOgGA2kQ26ytEFe7saC/3sYe0hRK32Vg5nvvTT8N7516nOun5/lUtS/Hyhytyd6fP1vcVj0@D3pVlvKjLK1x39gHayKk7rTZmI0ydaXeJD5JhUdyv4zL8bBq1FGO@IHMvW7UgGuMXLYGf1f4ItimgWCMpyCE8HgCRQJ8gywTFZcNZC5kgccEIsQwrm7H9Sj4axaEEV9QBpwn38igJ9s07q4k3OgXKcdX2Q8/LJJadxrdtuwA/Jy7OXAabhwaOzSiaZ6nWQxuEUCc@ksiha3IPcadmP75AYsitnDhov@a5y8)

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 19 bytes

```
{**&(#y)(~|/y=)':x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k#eJyFkF+LgkAUxd/9FGLLroY1uVGEsg/+GRtrUskJgwgKV00qbdMgaeuzr+VS7r50XwbmnHPP5ReIp3r9la3lHHv5BvkH9yYezxRFxNPLLL/sxYBu0kdpkawldhEso410lHJpz83PFJmxjIL6UJ+6OjEmtkEQwjYkhKjYgq4F8YiRGLf4gGMFjg0VEYaThPb8lpQVVYN6HxmDIS5sCGJsFXKrVGFlqqpZylMIdQcrDsTaYCRrpqwNNdtx7LEJFdeApq0XIQ1OiKMiLJvatVcoo2g4RIU4uM7vRgpQqyzbpSIAXvLph8kmaKbZ0lv7R2+1jEO/6SVb8HXw0yxK4hR0e0KvC7x94YjisJGt/IYfR+F2Cd6FTqfTqpUPRRnx7pCJ9BNIPP2HEWUdsltMaN83VGHx9I3G3fboqUL772oId9tzeDxdYfe457HiCpGnbwwrDT/svacr)

Takes the encoded message as `x` and the word as `y`. Returns `0N` (the integer null) if no possible occurrence was found.

- `(#y)(~|/y=)':x` use [`i f':x stencil`](https://k.miraheze.org/wiki/Windows) to apply `(~|/y=)` to each `(#y)`-length window of the input `x`

  - `(#y)` get the length of the input word
  - `(~|/y=)` check if any letters are in the same position in the word and the slice of the encoded message; then negate the resulting bitmask
- `**&` return the index of the first possible occurrence of the word in the encoded message

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>14</s> 13 bytes

Or **[12 bytes](https://tio.run/##VYsxCsIwGIXvktlLNM2f/ml/29BEWyjFVRBxEBe3OhTcRC/g5uAibq4ewDuYi8TYSb/lwXvfm2/WC798Xtyuc/3B9Uc/Xb3OW7c/u@7m@tOMQr4f1@fde980jGMCsq6kVROtLCJpsNbGVEBVAI3ZiFWhgJJDqWK0rB01LOKxAJmgSjMKAgJRMQzww99QA0hD3ACJdByJPBKZ0MboMgdeKci1DLqAiTUxUpSL4YRZhqFOv7C2/QA)** using 1-based indexing and returning `0` for no-occurrence.

```
←VoΠz≠⁰↓_L⁰ṫ²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYsxCsIwGIXvktlLNM2f/ml/29BEWyjFVRBxEBe3OhTcRC/g5uAibq4ewDuYi8TYSb/lwXvfm2/WC798Xtyuc/3B9UcfYrp6nbduf3bdzfWnGYV8P67Pu/e@aRjHBGRdSasmWllE0mCtjamAqgAasxGrQgElh1LFaFk7aljEYwEyQZVmFAQEomIY4Ie/oQaQhrgBEuk4EnkkMqGN0WUOvFKQaxl0ARNrYqQoF8MJswxDnX5hbfsB)

```
←                   # subtract 1 to get 0-based indexing
 V                  # index of first element of
            ṫ²      # all suffixes of arg 2,
        ↓_          # with n elements removed from the end, 
          L⁰        # where n is the length of arg 1,
                    # that satisfies
  ȯ¬                # NOT
    Σ               # any
     z=⁰            # elements are equal when zipped with arg 1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>9</s> 7 bytes

```
t"ƑÐƤi1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYy9DcIwFIRXQa5pGME/z3mOXxwrduQsQAFKScMWQMUASExAQUtE9mASg6ngq@47nW67Hsd9zjs2H6fDfNms8nRlj9vz9Lqfc2YCK9BD0tH03kRE8hBjlNRCaoEatlwwLqQCXaGpLRWHH4oPADqQCECqbrhyXFnlQ/CdA5EMOK/LCq1Flln63EMnoDMS47cHovYvKOhjkEjcqaJ1gb0B)

```
   ÐƤ      For each suffix,
  Ƒ        is it the same after
t          trimming off
 "         the corresponding letter of the word from each of its letters?
     i1    Find the first index of 1.
```

#### Wait, what?

This beats the original, `W€ḟ"ƑÐƤi1`, by completely dropping the step of wrapping each letter into a singleton list. As for *how*:

A Jelly string is a list of characters, which is to say it's a Python list of length-1 Python strings. For example, `“this”` is really `["t","h","i","s"]`.

Most list builtins are built to handle lists whether that's what they got or not, by passing all arguments through [`iterable`](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/blob/master/jelly/interpreter.py#L373), and in the case of a single character this wraps it in a singleton list to obtain a length-1 Jelly string. [`ḟ`](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/blob/master/jelly/interpreter.py#L234) does this, and as a result its output is also always a list--so `ḟ"`, mapped over corresponding pairs, gives a list of lists, and for it to ever not change a suffix of the ciphertext each of its characters has to be pre-wrapped to match.

However, [`t` *does not call `iterable` on its left argument*](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/blob/master/jelly/interpreter.py#L1772), so here `t"` operates on *the Python string characters themselves* of the ciphertext suffix, and either leaves them alone or trims them to `''`.

Finally, `Ƒ` performs a strict, non-vectorizing equality check, and `"` only maps its given link over pairs of corresponding elements up to the length of the shorter argument, placing the remainder of the longer argument into the result verbatim. If the ciphertext suffix is longer, the remainder automatically matches itself leaving only the prefix of length equal to the word to be considered, but if the word is longer, the result cannot be equal to the suffix because it is itself longer than the suffix.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 20 bytes

```
:ǎ'⁰l;ƛ⁰Zƛ≈;aßn;~ḃhḟ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCI6x44n4oGwbDvGm+KBsFrGm+KJiDthw59uO37huINo4bifIiwiIiwiQkhHRUZYV0ZUSVVQSVRISExQRVRUVENMT0VXT0VMTVxuV0VUVEVSQkVSSUNIVCJd)

I wrote this so long ago, waiting for `ḟ` to work on strings, that I forgot how this even works

Answer (score 1):

## [Jolf](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Jolf/), 14 bytes

[Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=IHNpz4FJIi4nW14kJl0&input=QkhHRUZYV0ZUSVVQSVRISExQRVRUVENMT0VXT0VMTQoKV0VUVEVSQkVSSUNIVA)

```
 siρI".'[^$&]
_s            search
  i            input 1 for
    I          input 2
   ρ            replacing (2 byte rho character)
     ".'         all characters
        [^$&]    with that
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 38 + 1 = 39 bytes

```
perl -E "$r=<>=~s!.![^$&]!gr;say@-if<>=~/$r/x" < input
```

where input looks like:

```
WETTERBERICHT
BHGEFXWFTIUPITHHLPETTTCLOEWOELMRXXPAKAXMAMTXXUDLTWTNHKELEPPLHPRQ
```

This is the same idea as the javascript one.

Comment: The 'x' is unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

### Java, 136 Characters

Regex-based solution inspired by [apsillers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/7796/apsillers) JavaScript version.

```
class L{public static void main(String[]a){a=a[0].split(a[1].replaceAll("(.)","[^$1]"));System.out.print(a.length>1?a[0].length():-1);}}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog) (v2), <s>16</s> 13 bytes

```
{sʰz₂}ᶠ∋↙.≠ᵐ∧
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU0/S8NAFP8qxw2iUDq4Osgl99K75pKeyZUclA5pKW1FWzCFoLVLhNIigqtbcXHtYlE/gt8i90XitYv6Gx7v/f693k3aH91eTYen1XxUfq3P52a5NcWDPis/Xy9N8ZQfzXKMjnGuc3yC7/dHP51MpjPUG6DxBM1G4wxdD7IsHQ7qeGEryo@dnYvy/bmaZ9/bO1MUi3K3MatHs3ypm/XGKmb1VlUd1MEOa4CnE0/xtuSKMSFBKeWKFiQtEEGktSQ@0QEJlNZtKlSiQuaDACkFk9EFruHEJiByIOIuU7hb62DiuBS8BuNNX1gDAyFaBwH@4J@gAbxYODEI2gwIDQn1qYxjGYXgJBxC6Vk7hbaKXSZISA8h5vvM0s09DgSnECrukv3T372Luj8)

Takes input as a list `[message, word]`. The header prints it all very prettily but the output of the actual predicate is just a 0-index if it succeeds and declarative failure if it doesn't.

```
{    }ᶠ          Find every possible
   z             zip of the word with
    ₂            an equal-length
 sʰ              contiguous substring of the ciphertext.
       ∋         One of those
          ≠ᵐ     contains no pair the elements of which are equal,
        ↙.  ∧    and its index is the output.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 46 bytes

Uses @apsillers' regex idea.

```perl
$a=<>=~s/./[^$&]/gr;/$a/g;$_=(length$a)/-4+pos
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l0dbGzrauWF9PPzpORS1WP73IWl8lUT/dWiXeViMnNS@9JEMlUVNf10S7IL/4/39XJMDl4erj4/8vv6AkMz@v@L@ur6megaHBf92CHAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
ṡ⁹L¤=S€i0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYy9DcIwFIRXQa4pWIDCP8@x4xfHih05C1CAsgAljEBFi4REQ0uRNohBkkUMpoKvuu90ut2m7/cpTcNlPgw4Xtd@Pt63q/S8kfHxOk3DOSXCVAGyizLo1umgFDoIIXCsIdaAFVkuCGVcgCyULg1mhx@ydwDSI/OAoqyosFQY4bx3jQUWNVgn80oZo0gi8XMPDYNGcxW@PSDWf0FAGzxXSK3IWmbIGw)

Uses 1-indexing, which is Jelly's default. [10 bytes](https://tio.run/##VYyxDcIwFERXQa4pWIAitr9jxz@OFTtyFqAAZQE6YAQqKJGQaGgp0gYxSLKIwVTwqnun021WXbeNcewv077H4bp00@G@Xky7c3zeyPB4Hcf@FCOhMgfRBuFVY5WXEi147xlWECrAksxnJKOMg8ilKjQmhx@StwDCIXWAvCgzbjKuuXXO1gZoUGCsSCuptSSRhM891BRqxaT/9oBY/QUOjXdMYmZ40iJB3g) to use 0-indexing. This returns \$0\$ if no occurrence is found (\$-1\$ for the 0-indexed version)

### How it works

```
ṡ⁹L¤=S€i0 - Main link. Takes M on the left and W on the right
   ¤      - Create a nilad:
 ⁹        -   W
  L       -   Length
ṡ         - Overlapping slices of length W of M
    =     - Compare for equality with W
     S€   - Count the number of 1s in each
       i0 - First index of 0, else 0 if not found
```

Comment: Took me a solid 5 minutes to figure out why the `S€` can't be `§`... if there aren't any slices, `=` gives W, and `§` tries to sum the string, but the `S` of each character leaves them unchanged since they're treated as scalars the same way as integers would be.

Answer (score 1):

## SM83/Z80, 30 bytes

First input (encrypted) in `hl`, second (unencrypted) in `de`.
Output in `bc`.

```
01 00 00 E5 D5 09 7E A7
28 11 1A A7 28 0A BE 23
13 20 F3 03 D1 E1 18 EB
02 FF FF D1 E1 C9
```

```
ecr:
 ld bc,0                // 01 00 00 setup bc
oloop:
 push hl                // E5       store originals
 push de                // D5
 add hl,bc              // 09       handle offset
iloop:
 ld a,(hl)              // 7E
 and a                  // A7       test if at end of arg 2
 jr z,succ              // 28 11    if so succeed
 ld a,(de)              // 1A       load encrypted char
 and a                  // A7       if at end
 jr z,fail              // 28 0A    fail
 cp (hl)                // BE       compare to other side
 inc hl                 // 23
 inc de                 // 13       next char
 jr nz,iloop            // 20 F3    if unequal, loop
 inc bc                 // 03       else inc offset
 pop de                 // D1
 pop hl                 // E1       reload originals
 jr oloop               // 18 EB    and jump back
fail:
 ld bc,-1               // 02 FF FF insert failure
succ:
 pop de                 // D1
 pop hl                 // E1       reload original args
 ret                    // C9       return
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 56 bytes

```
\(x,y)match(T,Map(\(i)all(x[i+seq(y)]!=y),seq(x)-1),0)-1
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMH6tMyi4pL4gvzi4syknFTbpaUlaboWNy1iNCp0KjVzE0uSMzRCdHwTCzRiNDI1E3NyNCqiM7WLUws1KjVjFW0rNXVA7ApNXUNNHQMgCdX_MDe1uDgxPdU2NUejuKSouCAns0RDycnD3dUtItwtxDM0wDPEw8MnwDUkJMTZx9813N_Vx1dJR0lJU5OrPL8oBVVfOFCZa5CTa5Cns0cIVBWquzWg9umANGtycWG13hUJ4LTLw9XHx58IOyAeXbAAQgMA)

Counterintuitively (at least to me), `match(TRUE,NA,nomatch=0)` returns `0`, rather than `NA`, but this is actually helpful here.
We could save 2 bytes (delete `-1`) by using R's native 1-based indexing; and a further 1 or 2 bytes by returning nothing (using `which()[1]`) or `NA` (delete `,0`) to indicate no occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>160</s> <s>153</s> 150 bytes

```cpp
#include<map>
int f(std::string c,std::string w){int i=-1,k,e=1;while(e&&w.size()+i++<c.size())for(e=k=0;k<w.size();)e+=c[i+k]==w[k++];return e?-1:i;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/NboJAFIXX8hQTjA2EsalbkDb8DA4yIhEMJtaFGQY7QZEIhqTGZ6fQ2oZFz@6e892bc2lRjA@UNs2Q5/R4Tdj0tC9eBZ5XIJXKKlHVsrrw/AAo7E@1fOsQro8nMINMn2j1Bz8yiT091c8l/2SSrHBFmdLHIKfni8T0TH/RsukvoclM0emWK9lO1@ttpig77cKq6yUH7G08Ubl2b4YJS3nOAN2XTKKwlkHRFqhSSRyVEIxKFYyS91yEbT9Qw7Zzx8iC8PcObWvz889Hpz3PJVm4CYPvc6KJZ8jZxE7krgM3wpgEKIoiiyxRvERkIUIxbg20MtHKtXAkypoAHuoOAEk0TMtGzgy7c4@0OEaELP/BUE99bPDINwg5ITFDROz5wrB9w/bsIAyDlY/M2EV@4LRbNlpHoYWJ4dv9Xex5uE3nnfq@15mdcW@@AA)

Comment: @ceilingcat: you can do
[157 bytes](https://tio.run/##bY9bb4JAEIWf5VdsMCa7AXt5BWnCZXGRFYlgMLE@mBXsBrsawJDU@NspVNvw0PM0c@abyRl2Po8PjDXNkAt2vOzTSVkVXBzeJC4qkMGy2mva3QJM7Xc1unYIN17UXBda/cGPKcwNrigT9lTyrxSicf0o0DU7FVD/bZ9zHfEMsg1X8q1h1JtcUbbocKpOQOhFWl0KAbh@u1fjV/3WDPdpxkUK2K5MIVNrBM5tiCqD8qhUwajUwGj/LmS1zQhqtc3dMUiS/r5ibXR@un/1ueMCIukqDX7OyRaZYneduLG3Cr2YEBriOI5tusDJAtO5rMpJa@ClhZeeTWIZ6RJ4qDsAoGxatoPdKfFmPm1xgild/IPhnvrY4DFfY@xG1IowdWZz0wlMx3fCKAqXAbYSDweh2245eBVHNqFm4PR3ie@Tdjrr1Pm35hs)

The code fails for two testcases though (as does my original one). I fixed it for a few extra bytes.

Comment: Plus, your initialization of k in the outer loop introduced another bug, where with each iteration, one less character was compared.

Comment: Turns out, it's even shorter without `goto` and without all the bugs...